# Creative ways to get from NY City to New Haven CT not using cars/vans

Tags: transit, transportation, new-york-city, connecticut

So far I have found(If Im wrong on the prices or times I would love to know):

**Greyhound-** buses from the port authority terminal
**Acela-** From Penn station about 1 hr 35 minutes (about $59)
**Northeast Regional-** From Penn station about 2 hrs (about $32)
**Vermonter-** From Penn station about 2 hrs(about $32)
**New Haven(Metro North)-** From Grand Central about 2 hrs(about $17.50)
**Port Jefferson Ferry-** 75 min (plus a 30 min walk NY side) (about $17 plus a $10.50 dollar train ride NY side and a 30 minute $23 amtrak or $3.50 MTN train ride CT side)
**Orient Point Ferry-** time about 2 hours? (Doesnt seem to be a public transit way to get here...and then a 1 hour $10.50 train ride)

Must be: direct transportation starting anywhere in New York city, Ending anywhere in New Haven, shouldn't require you to go to other states or countries(so commercial airlines do not work), cost less than 1000 dollars(so private helicopters do not work) and reasonably take less than 6 hours(so walking and biking do not work).

Also the form of transportation should either be regularly used, or original and not be just a different iteration of what is above.

They should also not include cars or vans in any way.

So is there any private boat, direct hopper flight, hot air balloon, train line service, etc. that I am not thinking of?

This may be a simple "no" or a "yes - this service" type answer.

Comment: It's about a 30-minute walk from the Port Jefferson train station to the ferry.  It's about a 2-hour ride from Penn Station to Port Jefferson, and costs $19 (peak) or $13.75 (off-peak) if you buy your ticket in advance, not $5.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the fare would be $5?

Comment: New Haven?  I think you mean *Metro-North*.  It's the New Haven Line, but I don't recall anyone, except the Conductor, calling it that.

Comment: In the summer of 2016, [Shoreline Aviation](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20160814043302/http://www.shorelineaviation.com/crbst_10.html) offered a seaplane shuttle service between Tweed New Haven Airport and the 23rd St. Seaplane Base in NYC.  No reference to this service currently appears on their website, so it's unclear whether they'll be doing so again over the coming summer.

Comment: Also, currently the only scheduled air service to Tweed New Haven is from PHL.  I suppose you could take Amtrak there and then catch a flight if you really wanted to.

Comment: @phoog changed it to 10.50 which should be more accurate. I just read the fare table I was looking at wrong.

Comment: How out of the way are you willing to go? Besides the direct route, you could also take Amtrak NYC-Albany-Springfield-New Haven, for instance.

Comment: Take an Uber. About $200. 1.5 hours to 2 hours depending on traffic. And it's door to door.

Comment: $10.50 is the fare from Jamaica.  Most of your other examples are from Manhattan locations such as Port Authority.  The fare from Manhattan, or indeed any station west of Jamaica, is $13.75 as I mentioned above.  You could spend $2.75 getting to Jamaica by subway and then take the LIRR from there, but then you'd be spending an extra hour or so in travel time to save fifty cents.

Comment: @cpast or indeed one could travel by Amtrak to LA and then from there to New Haven (perhaps by plane via Asia and Europe?).

Comment: Penn station -> Amtrak -> AirTrain -> EWR -> Flight to London -> [epic train journey across Europe](http://www.seat61.com/SilkRoute.htm) -> Beijing -> Kayak across the Pacific -> Hawaii -> Hovercraft to San Francisco -> hitchhike to Pompano Beach, Florida riding only in trucks (especially taco trucks) or Oscar Mayer Wienermobiles (not cars or vans) -> commandeer Goodyear Blimp -> blimp to ORD -> flight to HVN, but duct-taped to the wing -> parachute to destination.

Comment: Hilarious, but not what I am looking for.  I updated the question so hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: I think you invited some of the silliness by including the Orient Point ferry.  Why would anyone take a nearly three hour train ride plus a two hour ferry ride plus another one hour train ride to go nearly 50 miles too far east, when they can just take the direct train in a couple of hours?

Comment: It is a legitimate option for me. I have an infant, and don't want to have to use a car seat. Other than that, I don't have much constraining me either time wise or (within reason) money wise, but I am flying into New York, and need to get to New Haven.  At this point I just want to know what options are available, as it is not uncommon to find that there are unusual ways to get around in an area.  In AK you can take snow mobiles, sled dogs, or float planes, and in the USVI you can hire a boat, hitchhike, or paddleboard etc.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thank you for the suggestion, Ill look into Shoreline Aviation.